# Centos 7 settings for php7 firebird driver

Tags: php, centos, centos7, firebird

I have a web-based PHP script on Centos 7. I have to connect firebird database which is working on another server. 
I ran both of php and firebird on a windows computer for test.

I uncomment php_pdo_firebird.dll and php_interbase.dll in php.ini
I find for some information about ubuntu packages but not for centos.

Comment: Try to run yum -y install php php-interbase

Comment: dll is an extension for Windows, not for Centos, there it would be .so. However, it is unclear what you are actually asking. Consider asking on the firebird-php mailing list as well.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel he "runs on windows for test" whatever that should mean. but yes, it is totally unclear what is the situation he writes about. Sounds like a blog post of "road reports" kind. Or like a request to give him a step-by-step how-to for the any tasks he may or may chose to achieve. Or something yet else.